# How can I convert this to an integer? I keep getting this error: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10

Tags: python, integer, valueerror

I am having an error that says "ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:", and I cant find out how to fix it. I am trying to convert what I got from "data" to an integer, and I keep getting that error. Im sure there is a way to fix this, I just dont know. Heres my code:

```
import yfinance as yf                                                                                     
data = yf.download(tickers='SPY', period='90m', interval='15m')                                      
print("")                                                                                            
print("")                                                                                            
print("")                                                                                             
infotest = str(data)                                                                           
print(infotest)                                                                                    
StockValue7 = int(infotest[133:139])                                                               
StockValue6 = int(infotest[186:192])                                                        
print(StockValue7)                                                                          
print(StockValue6)
```

And heres the error with the output:[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MiUxC.png)

Comment: Please post all code and errors as plain text.  Images are hard to work with.

Comment: My guess is your string is less than 133 characters long, so you're trying to convert an empty string.  You printed the converted result.  What does it look like, exactly?

Answer (score 0):

`StockValue7` range is somewhere that its str is "      ".

and for sure you can not turn this into an integer.

Comment: I see what your trying to say, but when I print StockValue7 and StockValue6 without trying to turn them to an integer it prints the correct numbers without any extra characters.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help, then update your answer with more explanations and improved formatting. It will help others understand.